# Wrong value while getting last symbol in string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable **someText** where number is stored. Depending on last number I need to add different text. So I convert **someText** into stiring, get string length in **someTextLng** and substract for the last symbol **someTextLng**. 
`document.write(lastChar + "<br/>");` in my example returns 7 - all ok.
Continuing with if and getting surprise - lastChar = 1. But why? Where is my mistake?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var someText =  312347;
someText= someText.toString();
someTextLng = someText.length-1;
var lastChar = someText.substr(someTextLng, 1);
document.write(lastChar + "<br/>");
if (lastChar = "1") {
document.write(lastChar+"&nbsp;Day")
}
else if (lastChar = "2") {
document.write(lastChar+"&nbsp;DayZ")
}
else {
alert ("Wuza");
}
</script>
```

Comment: if(lastChar = "1") will always be true. use (lastChar === "1") to be sure of your comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `==` to match the value of `lastChar`. To get the lastChar you can use reminder operator:

```
var lastChar = someText % 10;

if (lastChar == 1) {
    document.write(lastChar+"&nbsp;Day")
}
else if (lastChar == 2) {
    document.write(lastChar+"&nbsp;DayZ")
}
else {
    alert ("Wuza");
}
```

Comment: OMG, such a silly mistake. Forgot about it - wasn't using JS for a long time. Thanks a lot for explanation. I'll accept your answer in 9 mins.

Comment: Happens with the best of lot at times!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [reminder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) `%` for the last digit?

```
var last = number % 10;
```

and later

```
if (last === 1) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Tbh I solved my task with switch at last. There is a bit more conditions than odd and even numbers -  word lore of Russian language roks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var someText =  312347;
someText= someText.toString();
someTextLng = someText.length-1;
var lastChar = someText.substr(someTextLng, 1);
console.log(lastChar + "<br/>");
if (lastChar == "1") {
   console.log(lastChar+"&nbsp;Day")
}
else if (lastChar == "2") {
   console.log(lastChar+"&nbsp;DayZ")
}
else {
   alert ("Wuza");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for something that equal to something else it's `===` not `=`

Your code should be like that

```
if (lastChar === "1") {
  document.write(lastChar+"&nbsp;Day")
}
else if (lastChar === "2") {
  document.write(lastChar+"&nbsp;DayZ")
}
else {
  alert ("Wuza");
}
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastChar =  (312347 % 10).toString;
document.write(lastChar + "<br/>");
if (lastChar === "1") {
  document.write(lastChar+"&nbsp;Day")
} else if (lastChar === "2") {
  document.write(lastChar+"&nbsp;DayZ")
} else {
  alert ("Wuza");
}
</script>
```